# Create docker file for my angular application to build one image only one and multi containers for each environment

Tags: angular, docker

I have this docker file configurations for my angular application and It works fine to build a multiple images for each environment and create any numbers of containers

```
# Stage 1: Use the official Node.js image as the base image
FROM node:14.10-alpine AS node

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# copy these over first and run 'npm install' so the node_modules will be cached
# until the package.json / lock changes
COPY package*.json ./

# Install the dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the entire project directory into the container
COPY . .

# Build the Angular app for the desired environment
ARG environment
RUN npm run build:$environment

# Delete the not needed source after the build is done
RUN rm -rf src

# Stage 2: Create the final image with Nginx
# Use the nginx:alpine base image
FROM nginx:alpine

# Copy the compiled Angular application from the 'node' image to the nginx HTML directory
COPY --from=node  /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

# Copy the custom nginx configuration file to the appropriate location to overwrite the default configuration
COPY ./nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

using `docker build --pull --rm  --build-arg environment=local -f "Dockerfile" -t imag_name:latest "."`  for build and `docker run --rm -d -p 80:80/tcp image_name:latest` for creating a container and run it in specific port

but I need to update it to build only one image once for all environments and multi containers from it for each environment could you please tell me how the configurations should look like

Comment: The `npm run build:$environment` stage looks like you have a different Javascript-level build procedure for each environment.  You can't build a single image that contains all environments, unless you have multiple copies of the application in the image.

Answer (score 0):

the is the solution for my problem to build only one image and multi containers for each environment from the same image
https://gabrielemilan.dev/publish-same-docker-image-with-angular-application-to-any-environments-edbfc454c6bb

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).